# UICollectionView Not Keeping UITextfield Input

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield, uicollectionviewcell

Bear with me as this is a difficult issue to describe. I have two `UICollectionViews`: `MainCollectionView` and `NestedCollectionView`. The `MainCollectionViewCell` holds a `UILabel` and the `NestedCollectionView`. In turn, the `NestedCollectionViewCell` holds either a `UILabel` or a `UITextfield`. Whether the `UILabel` or `UITextfield` is shown depends on the content for the `NestedCollectionViewCell`.

My issue is as follows: when the user selects the `NestedCollectionViewCell` and the content is set to show a `UITextfield`, then a keyboard for user input shows up. This is expected.

However, when the user inputs some text then scrolls to another cell in the `MainCollectionView`, the `NestedCollectionView` gets reset and the `UITextfield.text` is set to the default. In other words, the inputted text is not preserved.

Any advice how I can solve this?

Comment: well when you scroll you dismiss the keyboard and it will trigger a didEnd event for your textfield and you can capture for that specific cell once it goes back to view just display whatever you captured. Just an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputted text in `UITextField` is lost, because whenever you scroll your `UITableView` it will automatically destroy cells which are no longer visible, and this also required for better memory management otherwise your app will consume more memory. So when you come back to your previous cell, you have newly generated `UITalbeViewCell`. So your data is lost, because you haven't persist it.

So as a solution whenever your `textFieldDidEndEditing` called or whenever you dismiss keyboard store your `UITextField` values into some object, and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method check if object has value then fill it to your `UITextField`.

In this way you always have your previously entered value as it is.